# Angular schema form access Object with Arrays from Form

Tags: angularjs, angular-schema-form

I have a scenario where i need to display arrays in side a named object like this:

```
   "actions": {
    "singleSelection": [
      {
        "chartable": false,
        "label": ""
      }
    ]
  }
```

I have accomplished it with the following schema:

```
"schema": {
    "type": "object",
    "title": "smart_report",
    "properties": {
    "actions": {
        "title": "Actions",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "singleSelection": {
            "title": "Action: Single selection",
            "type": "array",
            "maxItems": 10,
            "items": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "field": {
                  "title": "Field name",
                  "type": "string"
                },
                "label": {
                  "title": "Label",
                  "type": "string",
                  "description": "Label will be used for column name."
                },
                "chartable": {
                  "title": "Chartable",
                  "type": "boolean"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
}
```

Now am trying to set the 'notitle' flag on 'actions' in from and trying to access the properties of 'actions', but its not working as expected:

```
{
      "key": "actions",
      "notitle": true,
      "properties": {
        "key": "singleSelection",
        "notitle": true,
        "startEmpty": true
      }
    },
```

I still see title for actions as well for 'singleSelection' and 'stratEmpty' is also not set.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the titles from the schema, as well as using the notitle attribute it should work.

(In case you remove the title, but do not use the notitle attribute, the title will be displayed with the same name as the key).